# I can't get a reply from PHP using Javascript (Ajax). While I am able to display results on PHP page, I want it back on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, web-services

I am trying to build a very simple web service using PHP. But I am unable to get response from the PHP (which is sending the data in a JSON format). When I print my responseText using console.log(), it shows as empty string. PHP is accepting some data using get method and when I enter PHP file and query parameter through url, data is displayed. I am unable to bring this data back to my HTML file. Please help me. I tried reading lots of question on https://stackoverflow.com/ and i also referred to lots of code and videos but cant find any solution yet

This is my HTML and Javascript code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Agent Details</title>
<head>
<body>  
<form method="get">
<h1>Enter Agent ID</h1>
<input name="userd" id="userid" type="text" placeholder="enter agent id"></input><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="display">
</div>
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp);
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","raw");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    if(isset($_GET["userid"])){
        $username=$_GET["userid"];
        $query="SELECT * FROM agents WHERE agent_id='$username'";
        $results=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
        $myJson=json_encode($rows);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $myJson;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

Screenshots

This show when I directly access PHP file its echos output:
[php running successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atrHG.jpg)

Here you can see that communication is happening between client and web-service since status is "200" and status message is "OK". But when I access PHP through Ajax, responseText is empty
[response text shown as empty when used ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr08t.jpg)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: thanks @AlexHowansky

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing any parameters in your AJAX query: `xhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);`. In the PHP example screenshot, you're passing userid as a GET parameter: `test.php?userid=1`.

Comment: I edited my code as `xhttp.open("GET","test.php?userid="+getElementById("userid").value, true);` but the problem now arising is this script is executed as the page loads and not when the form is submitted and as @elfu suggested to use a function and call it. I did that too but now what's happening is function is called and executed once only and the result which is displayed using DOM inside function disappears quickly. Please help me

Comment: This is a much longer topic than what SO questions are for. You need to learn in depth how forms and scripts work. Try reading up on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

First: You are not passing any params via AJAX in line:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "test.php", true);
```

Second: You are sending when the page starts, and does not have a value defined in the field, the correct manner would be create a function with, call it when the button is pressed (remove the SUBMIT value for TYPE, and replace it with BUTTON), then call a function, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Agent Details</title>
<head>
<body>  
<form method="get">
<h1>Enter Agent ID</h1>
<input name="userd" id="userid" type="text" placeholder="enter agent id"></input><br>
<input type="button" onclick="ajax()" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="display">
</div>
<script>
function ajax(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp);
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "test.php?userd="+document.getElementById('userid').value, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I thought passing parameters through URL would be enough and I used `<form>` for that. I tried this code to pass parameter in AJAX call `xhttp.open("GET","test.php?userid="+getElementById("userid").value, true);` but it is unsuccessfull. Then I did this `xhttp.open("GET","test.php?userid=1", true);` Then it successfully displays first row but what happening here is result is getting displayed as soon as the page loads so i tried to put it into function as you said but then it displays results but in a flash results disappears.

Comment: I think that you've left your old `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` and the `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { ... }`.
If that's the case then just remove it, the function should do the trick.
If that's not the case, then post your code so I can investigate.